# Append div which is saved as a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, append

How can i append to a DOM element a div which is saved as a string in a variable?

as for example:

```
var toAppend = "<div id="divID" class="hello" contenteditable>hi hi</div>";
```

how can I append it using for example:

```
$('#parentDiv').appendChild( ... );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As follow:**

```js
var str = '<div id="divID" class="hello" contenteditable>hi hi</div>';
$('#parentDiv').append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parentDiv'/>
```

Comment: So with jquery .append i can append it as it is, cool thanks.

Comment: Does it append it below the parentDiv in this case? If i have other divs inside parentDiv already for instance, it goes as last?

Comment: It works just like appendChild.  It adds the element(s) as the last children of the element you are appending to